# using only mysql for a referral system

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup a referral system, pretty simple but the difficult part is that I'd like to use only SQL queries very limited PHP, here is my extremerly lame attemp:

```
IF EXISTS( SET @UID=userid FROM tbl_users WHERE username = 'seang' 
   THEN
       BEGIN
           UPDATE tbl_profile
              SET refcount=refcount+1
           WHERE userid = SELECT @UID 
           AND UPDATE tbl_profile SET referrer= SET @UID
      END;
ENDIF;
```

Obviously that's very wrong, but I still tried :/
Here is what I'm trying to do, in english. check if the username exists of the person who referred the new user (seang referred him/her), if seang does exist we'll increase his referral count by 1 and well set the new users referrer to seang's userid. seang's username and userid is stored in tbl_users, his referral count is stored in tbl_profile. seang's userid is also in the tbl_profile table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a stored procedure for this sort of thing is massive over-kill considering you can do it with a simple `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_profile r, tbl_users u, tbl_profile p
  SET p.refcount=p.refcount+1,
      r.referrer=u.userid
  WHERE r.referrer IS NULL
    AND p.userid=u.userid
    AND u.username=?
    AND r.userid=?
```

Where `?` is a placeholder value for your user's name and the second placeholder is for the referred user's userid.

**This query demonstrates why this is really not a good idea** to lean so heavily on SQL to do things. This gets exponentially more complicated as you try and stay in the SQL domain.

Keep in mind there's no reason to use "only SQL queries" for this. Application layers are important and often a better place to perform certain operations like resolving usernames to ID values.

Consider: If some day your user and profile tables are stored on different database servers most ORMs will deal automatically but your SQL only code will cease to work.

Comment: This will increment the `refcount` and set the `referrer` of all users in `tbl_profile` table who don't currently have a `referrer` set.  The OP wants to update the `refcount` of the *referring* user's profile, and set the `referrer` on the *new user's* profile.

Comment: Ah, I forgot a condition. Let me edit. The original query also sets referrer info for everyone which is probably super wrong.

Comment: Now it increments the `refcount` of the referrer's profile (correct) but also sets that user's `referrer` to himself (incorrect)—and both of those things only if that user's `referrer` was previously `NULL` (incorrect).

Comment: I think this demonstrates how doing it all on one hairball of a query is a bad idea when three simple queries would be easy to get right.

Comment: Agreed, though it can be done with an additional join with `tbl_profile` for the new user's profile.

Comment: It might be a four way update which, honestly, I wouldn't trust as far as I could throw it. One little mistake and you're going to scramble two tables **badly**. I've added code here that gets it 80% working. The remainder is, as they say, an exercise for the reader.

Comment: you are right, i guess this is massive overkill to depend totally on SQL, i thought it would be quicker to do as much as possible using sql but didn't take compatibility in to consideration. This is easily done combining PHP with SQL but it was also interesting to see :)

Comment: It's an educational exercise, for sure, I mean I've learned something about some of the nuances of the `UPDATE` statement because I've never tried to make one query do this much work.

Comment: I prefer this to 3 queries - but I don't like the archaic comma joins